# why is detached entity treated as transient?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate as JPA provider. I have fetched `account` entity from the database and `detached` it. So, the account entity must now be in a detached state.
Now when I try to `persist` the detached entity, I was expecting it to fail, as `entitymananger.persist` method works only on `transient` and `managed` entities. **But it is running INSERT query on database.**

Further debugging the `entitymananger.persist` implementation, I found that it is considering account entity as `TRANSIENT`. I put the breakpoint [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultPersistEventListener.java#L102) to see entity state,

The code used for testing:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class)
public class HibernateTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Commit
    public void testDetached() {
        Account account = entityManager.find(Account.class, 1); // account is now managed entity
        entityManager.detach(account); // detach the account entity
        entityManager.persist(account);// entityManager is treating account as transient object and ran INSERT query on the database

    }

}
```

Adding the Account class

```
@Entity
@lombok.Data
@Table(name = "account")
class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private int userid;

    @Column(name = "balance")
    private int balance;

}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Why is `entitymanager.persist` considering `detached` entity as `transient` ?
2. I tried understanding Hibernate determination of whether an entity is `transient` or `detached` ([code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractSaveEventListener.java#L485)). the logic is complex and couldn't internalize why it is done the way it is done.

Please let me know if you need any further details. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post `Account` class?

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: do you get some kind of constraint violation when you run this test?

Comment: yes. because of the database primary key constraint on `userid` column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An entity is considered DETACHED if :

```
1. ID is not null (otherwise it is transient)
2. It is not managed
3. It has not been removed
```

Im not sure how you are assigning the ID property, but i guess the problem is somewhere around there.

Leave the ID generation to hibernate:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue  <<<<<<<
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private int userid;
```

That should fail the test.

Comment: What if the id is not generated?

Comment: What do you mean by id not generated? Using @GeneratedValue?

Comment: I mean if it is provided, not generated.

Comment: @EugenCovaci if the generator is not provided, hibernate is treating as `transient` object. As @Ben pointed, if  `userid` is annotated with `GeneratedValue`, it's treated as `detached` entity